# rosserial/cmake flashing fails with atmega168

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm once again working on getting rosserial to work with a atmega168 based motor controller. With the arduino IDE, I can flash the rosserial "hello world" example just fine, but with the cmake-based system, the "make upload" command always aborts at the verification step at about 6 to 20% with "stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding".

I changed node_handle.h like so:

```
  template<class Hardware,
           int MAX_SUBSCRIBERS=5,
           int MAX_PUBLISHERS=5,
           int INPUT_SIZE=128,
           int OUTPUT_SIZE=128>
  class NodeHandle_
```

to make the code fit into the limited memory of the atmega168 (It would be good if this could be set without editing in the rosserial_client package btw :) /edit: Just noticed one can actually do this by using `ros::NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware,5,5,128,128>` instead of `ros:NodeHandle`)

What I get when flashing is:

```
 make upload
[ 76%] Built target diecimila_CORE
[100%] Built target chatter
Scanning dependencies of target chatter-upload
avrdude: successfully opened stk500v1 device -- please use -c stk500v1

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9406
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
a    vrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: reading input file "chatter.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (9774 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 7.60s

avrdude: 9774 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against chatter.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file chatter.hex:
avrdude: input file chatter.hex contains 9774 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ##########                                         | 19% 1.35savrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/chatter-upload] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/chatter-upload.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/upload.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [upload] Error 2
```

Is there a quick way to disable the verification step? Seeing how it works with the arduino IDE upload, I suspect that the verification step fails because of timing issues or so and not because flashing went bad.

Update:
After updating to most recent mercurial version and setting `<ArduinoHardware,4,4,128,128>` for `nh` , I can get the Atmega168 to publish on the chatter topic (Flashing still seems to fail sometimes though). However, if I add a subscriber, I can still flash the system, but rosserial fails to connect every time. If I upload the code using the arduino IDE, it works. Interestingly, the Arduino IDE reports a sketch size of

```
Binary sketch size: 9282 bytes (of a 14336 byte maximum)
```

while 'make upload' of the cmake based script tells me

```
avrdude: writing flash (11220 bytes):
```

for the exact same code

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12138/rosserial/cmake-flashing-fails-with-atmega168/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2011-11-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-11-29**:
Ahem, yes this is possible. I see I have to work on my mercurial skills :) Will report back later today.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-11-29**:
ros.h should contain a big series of "#if defined(**AVR_ATmega8**).." type things, if not, you don't have the latest version (did you possibly "pull" but not "update"?)

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-11-29**:
I'm running the latest version from mercurial, so this should be used already, right? Looking into the sources generated in src/ros_lib for my package, I see the default <25,25,512,512> parameters. Or does this get changed during compilation somehow?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-11-29**:
The latest release of rosserial (0.3.0) should be setting the node handle parameters based on the chip -- your mega168 would get <6,6,150,150> -- does that not fit in RAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, updated it. It now works with a <ArduinoHardware,4,4,128,128> setting (I get chatter topic echoes). With the default nodehandle, I get only sync failed. It appears the hex file is still too large. (It would be great to have a "make size" target btw :) )

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0